# PHP Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found

Tags: php, windows, httprequest, pecl

I was wondering how I can't get rid of this error. I have a PHP 5.3 running on a Windows Server.

In one of my file, I need to do a HttpRequest. The problem is that I need a specific *.dll (pecl_http.dll) that I can't find. Is there another way to do this, or has someone this *.dll for PHP 5.3 ?

Thanks for your help

Alexandre

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the functionality of http_parse_headers without PECL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368574/how-to-get-the-functionality-of-http-parse-headers-without-pecl)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look down the list here: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ you'll see 4 versions of php_http.  The 4 versions are all options of 'non-thread-safe' and 'thread-safe' (filename shows 'nts' or nothing), and VC6 or VC9.

To see if you need vc6 or vc9,  load up phpinfo, and look at 'Compiler' near the top.  A bit further down, you'll see 'Thread Safety' if this is enabled, go for the one that doesn't say 'nts'.

Answer (score 0):

install (or reinstall) the package

```
$ pecl install -f pecl_http-1.7.6
```

or use curl - [this is a working snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31318117/1166727)