# Linux server on HostGator says Class 'HTTPRequest' not found

Tags: php, linux

i am hosting a website on hostGator with Linux cpanel.
i am using httpRequest and Curl functions in my php script. But when i put the script on Live Server it says,

```
Fatal error: Class 'HTTPRequest' not found in home/directory/file.php on line42
```

Any way to set up the server as i,ve update the php version to 5.5 on server from Cpanel.

How to configure these settings i have no idea.
Don't Link to these Questions not Helping in my case:
[PHP Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980505/php-fatal-error-class-httprequest-not-found)
[HttpRequest not found in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579407/httprequest-not-found-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this Alternative, as if you are on shared hosting you might not able to get the desired modules:
instead of httprequest use CURL which is built in php module, and easily enabled on linux hosting servers as well.
Check this out might be helpful.
[Alternative for HTTPRequest in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212407/alternative-for-httprequest-in-php/23214486#23214486)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pecl module that is apparently not installed on your server. You can either install via cPanel -> PECL or using the pecl cli pecl install

http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php

Looks like I was wrong there does not appear to be a pecl manager in cPanel just pear.

So you need to ssh to the server and use the pecl command else write support@hostgator.com and request they install the extension for you

Comment: updated post - I work @ hostgator so if you don't have ssh access you can enable via your billing url