# Is there a simple solution to fetching a particular custom header in a CURL response using PHP?

Tags: php, http, curl

When I fetch all headers via

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);  
$header_size = curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$result = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
```

I get an output like

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 06 Jul 2015 14:58:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 302 Found
Location: https://data.myserver.com 
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id: 9e2a562ec3ba73a72702e84fa7177c56
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Runtime: 0.046013
X-Rack-Cache: miss
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Varnish: 945594494
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

I only want the 'Location:' value, in Java it was easy however in PHP, I could not find a simple elegant solution without using regex.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589889/returning-header-as-array-using-curl

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help you:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
var_export($info);
```

Result:

```
array (
  'url' => 'http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php',
  'content_type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  'http_code' => 200,
  'header_size' => 596,
  'request_size' => 81,
  'filetime' => -1,
  'ssl_verify_result' => 0,
  'redirect_count' => 0,
  'total_time' => 0.79269400000000001,
  'namelookup_time' => 0.028351999999999999,
  'connect_time' => 0.21638999999999997,
  'pretransfer_time' => 0.21643999999999997,
  'size_upload' => 0,
  'size_download' => 62628,
  'speed_download' => 79006,
  'speed_upload' => 0,
  'download_content_length' => -1,
  'upload_content_length' => 0,
  'starttransfer_time' => 0.41433799999999998,
  'redirect_time' => 0,
  'redirect_url' => '',
  'primary_ip' => '72.52.91.14',
  'certinfo' => 
  array (
  ),
  'primary_port' => 80,
  'local_ip' => '192.168.12.184',
  'local_port' => 36041,
)
```

And you can get `http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php` through `$info['url']`.