# JSON Response with REST GET - PHP

Tags: php, json, rest, curl

I am using cURL and REST to access a database and a query search, i am getting the following response when i use `echo $response`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Fri, 05 Aug 2016 06:53:02 GMT Server: Apache Content-Language: en-US RNT-Time: D=58292 t=1470379982660626 RNT-Machine: 128.65 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: application/json { "items": [ { "tableName": "Country", "count": 1, "columnNames": [ "id" ], "rows": [ [ "12" ] ] } ], "links": [ { "rel": "self", "href": "https://test.cust.com/services/rest/connect/v1.3/queryResults?query=select%20ID%20from%20CO.Country%20where%20CO.Country.Country=%27USA%27" }, { "rel": "canonical", "href": "https://test.cust.com/services/rest/connect/v1.3/queryResults" }, { "rel": "describedby", "href": "https://test.cust.com/services/rest/connect/v1.3/metadata-catalog/queryResults", "mediaType": "application/schema+json" } ] }
```

i tried to use `JSON_decode()` but so far i got nowhere, how can i get my parameters here ? to be more specific, the "id" value.

Comment: are you on client side or server? i.e. request is from client to server-server or server-server?

Comment: @GoldunoSupport client-server

Comment: request is through ajax? if den use      data = JSON.parse(data); where data is response from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right you have 2 options:

- turn off receiving headers `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0)`
- break your response by `\r\n\r\n`, you'll get `header` and `body`

```php
list($header, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2)
```

Comment: That helped me a lot by removing the header , now i got a full JSON response, i added : `$test=$res->items[0]->rows[0]; echo $test[0];`
i got the row value , thanks

Answer (score 1):

The response which posted here is seems like server response sending to the client browser,

so, you have few of options to parse this data

1. In case of this response must be parsed using PHP then you can try parsing data using `parse_str()` in PHP by following way.

   ```
   if (FALSE !== (stripos($response, '{'))) {

   $data = trim(substr($response, stripos($response, '{')));

       $data_arr = array();

       parse_str($data, $data_arr);

       print_R($data_arr);

       //Digging down using parse_str() in php

   } else {

       echo "No data found.";
   }
   ```
2. Either use client side javascript/jquery/client side script to parse json from response on browser.
3. [Returning header as array using Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589889/returning-header-as-array-using-curl)

Comment: okay , i got `Array ( [{ ____"items":_] => Array ( [ { "tableName": "CO.Country", "count": 1, "columnNames": [ "id" ] => select ID from CO.Country where CO.Country.Country='USA'" }, { "rel": "canonical", "href": "https://test.cust.com/services/rest/connect/v1.3/queryResults" }, { "rel": "describedby", "href": "https://test.cust.com/services/rest/connect/v1.3/metadata-catalog/queryResults", "mediaType": "application/schema json" } ] } ) ) `
how can i get the id attribute now?

Comment: Then you need to dig down dipper and iterate over response data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JSON_decode().

Use:

```
$obj = $_POST['items']; // for post
```

for get:

```
$obj = $_GET['items'];
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @evilive, i was able to get it to work:

1- turn of receiving headers curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0)

2- `$test=$res->items[0]->rows[0];`
   `echo $test[0];`

Answer (score -2):

```
$response;//Suppose your respond is this.

$obj = json_decode($response);
```

Then you can access your parameters. 
Example: 
    $obj-> items